# Devise - sign_in within namespace not working after password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using Devise, I am attempting to allow users to update their passwords using Solution 3 here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

I am using namespaces though, so my controller code looks like so:

```
def update_profile

    @user = current_vendors_user

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :vendor) then
        sign_in :vendors, @user, :bypass => true
        flash[:notice] = 'Profile successfully updated'
        return redirect_to vendors_root_path
    else
        render :action => 'index'
    end
end
```

... where my namespace is :vendors.

No matter what I do, the user gets logged out. If I output "current_vendor_user" after "sign_in" then I see that the user is logged in, but after the redirect they've been logged out. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I think my issue is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540085/user-sessions-invalid-after-changing-password-but-only-with-multiple-threads

Comment: No never resolved unfortunately!